# How to using Objective C Class in Swift framework?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm coding a swift framework project,

needs to call functions from other objective-c framework,

when I try to using bridge header, I got error,

Is possible to using Objective C class in Swift framework project ?

UPDATED:

the error was

**:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1**

Comment: Yes it is, but you'll need to provide more details as to what error you are seeing if you expect a better answer than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to wrap the Objective-C classes to a framework, then import the framework to my swift framework.